# Resultant Velocity

Tags: vectors

A flat rectangular barge, $48m$ long and $20m$ wide, is headed directly across a stream at $4.5km/hr$. The stream flows at $3.8km/hr$. What is the velocity, relative to the river bed, of a person walking diagonally across the barge at $5km/hr$ while facing the opposite upstream bank?

OK - so doing the math with the angles I now get the speed of the man relative to the river bed to be 2.6637 - does this sound right? Still not sure I'm adding the vectors correctly.

Comment: where are you stuck?

Comment: Which diagonal is the person walking across?

Comment: I calculated the barge speed relative to the river bed at 5.8898km/hr and the angle of the person relative to the barge at 22.62 degrees - not sure how to add the vector to get the speed of the walker relative to the river bed.

Comment: The person is walking on the diagonal of the barge upstream towards the opposite bank

Comment: Sorry - I know it is probably a simple question but I'm just getting my head around vectors and stuff and am a bit stuck with this one :)

Comment: @DavidH "a person walking diagonally across the barge... while facing the opposite upstream bank", so in a sense he is going upstream.

Comment: @tpb261 That makes sense now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, stream is along positive x direction,

1. Barge velocity, $V_b = 4.5 \hat{j}$

   Stream velocity,  $V_s = 3.8 \hat{i}$

   person velocity, $V_p = 5(48\hat{i}-20\hat{j})/sqrt(48^2+20^2)$

Net velocity of person = $V = V_b+V_s+V_p$

Answer (score 0):

Do it stepwise. His speed relative to the barge is 5km/hr ($V \_MB$) and you know the velocity of the barge relative to the riverbed ($V \_BR $).

If the velocity of the man relative to the riverbed is ($V \_MR$)

$$V \_MR = V \_MB + V \_BR $$
Make sure to consider only the components of the velocity in the relevant directions.

Comment: Do I need to account for the angle that the person is walking relevant to the barge though? He will be walking against the stream direction so I assume it would be less than 5km/hr relevant to the riverbed.

Comment: Yes. If the angles are confusing, try using components of all the velocities in 2 orthogonal directions(preferably horizontally and vertically.

Comment: OK - so doing the math with the angles I now get the speed of the man relative to the river bed to be 2.6637 - does this sound right? Still not sure I'm adding the vectors correctly.